# i3bar/i3blocks FontAwesome not shown correctly

Tags: arch-linux, i3

I've just made a full system update (ArchLinux, probably i3wm and/or i3blocks and/or FontAwesome has/have been updated), and I am not able to recover the special symbols in my i3bar (+ i3blocks).
Everything else is just shown fine except the missing special symbols for volume/speaker, battery, ...

I already tried reinstalling the font, and refreshing the fc-cache, restarting the system, x11, i3, changing the font size.

Printing: `i3blocks -c ~/.config/i3blocks/config` in terminal works fine and provides the expected result.

```
bar {
    status_command i3blocks
    tray_output primary
    font pango:Hack Bold 10
    font pango:Hack, Font Awesome 11
}
```

`50%  Sunny 15 °C   212G/869G  91% ⏳00:00    0.84%  14-09-2023 11:36:20`

Starting i3blocks from terminal gives: `[libi3] ../libi3/font.c Using Pango font Hack,Font Awesome, size 11` telling me, that it loads the correct font, even so the symbols are not visible:

`50%  Sunny 15 °C    212G/869G   91%  00:00     0.84%   14-09-2023 11:36:20`

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix it?

Thank you very much in advance for your support.

(PS.: knowing which of the software packages have changed would probably simplify the search for a solution slightly, but I can't did not pay attention...)